# How to renew the expiration date of your subscription?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I use plugin WooCommerce Subscribe.
I need to update my current subscription. I am currently subscribed until 24.02.2024, and if I purchase an additional subscription for one month or one year, the current subscription will be extended to 24.03.2024 for monthly subscriptions or 24.02.2025 for yearly subscriptions.

I attempted to find a solution on the internet and within the plugin settings

Comment: How did you pay for it in the first place?